# Running a 2nd command as a fallback with the same arguments as the 1st command

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, macos, compatibility

I would like to run the following command:

```bsh
tar  --sort=name --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 --mtime='UTC 2020-01-01' -cvf api.tar api
```

But need the following fallback for macOS:

```bsh
gtar --sort=name --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 --mtime='UTC 2020-01-01' -cvf api.tar api
```

(Note: the arguments are identical.)

Can I call `gtar` first, and then `tar` as a fallback, as a one-liner, writing the arguments only once?

Comment: You can put the argument string in a variable, say `ARGS`, then call `gtar $ARGS` followed by `tar $ARGS`. If you use Bash interactively, you should also look up "quick substitution".

Comment: @berndbausch, putting that argument list in a single string variable will fail immediately (because of the space in `UTC 2020-01-01`). See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I call gtar first, and then tar as a fallback, as a one-liner, writing the arguments only once?

To answer this as asked: this can be done as a simple implementation of storing the arguments in an array. (Bash/ksh/zsh. See [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable) for the issues and the POSIX-compatible workaround.)

```
args=(--sort=name --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 --mtime='UTC 2020-01-01' -cvf api.tar api)
if ! tar "${args[@]}"; then
    echo "using 'tar' failed, retrying with 'gtar'" >&1
    gtar "${args[@]}"
fi
```

or a as a one-liner, if you insist:

```
tar "${args[@]}" || gtar "${args[@]}"
```

Though this doesn't tell *why* it failed, and would try to retry with the other tar even if the problem is something like a non-accessible directory.

Another alternative would be to only rerun the command if the first one errors with "command not found". The shells usually set `$?` to 127 in that case. Of course, this requires flipping `gtar` first, since `tar` probably exists, in some form.

```
gtar "${args[@]}"
ret=$?
if [ "$ret" = 127 ]; then
    tar "${args[@]}"
    ret=$?
fi
```

The test `[ "$? = 127 ]` trashes the value of `$?`, hence the extra variable to hold the actual exit status if needed.

In the specific case of the two tars, [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669733/170373) about checking beforehand is also a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you install GNU `tar` by means of installing the `gnu-tar` package using Homebrew on macOS, you will notice the following message in the terminal:

```
GNU "tar" has been installed as "gtar".
If you need to use it as "tar", you can add a "gnubin" directory
to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

This means that your `tar` command at the start of your question will work as expected if you first set `PATH` as shown in the `gnu-tar` installation message above.

```bsh
PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
tar  --sort=name --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 --mtime='UTC 2020-01-01' -cvf api.tar api
```

Updating `PATH` conditionally:

```bsh
if [ "$(uname)" = Darwin ]; then
    PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
fi

tar  --sort=name --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 --mtime='UTC 2020-01-01' -cvf api.tar api
```

You could also test with `command -v`:

```bsh
if command -v gtar >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    tar=gtar
elif command -v tar >/dev/null 2>&1 && tar --version | grep -q -F GNU 2>/dev/null; then
    tar=tar
else
    echo 'No GNU tar available' >&2
    exit 1
fi

"$tar" --sort=name --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 --mtime='UTC 2020-01-01' -cvf api.tar api
```

This tests whether `gtar` exists as a command.  If it does, the variable `tar` is set to the string `gtar`.  If it doesn't exist, we test for `tar`, and if `tar` exists we test whether `tar --version` returns something that contains the substring `GNU` and assign the variable `tar` the string `tar`.  But if the tests fail, we bail out with a diagnostic message.

Later, if we didn't bail out with an error message, we use `"$tar"` as the command.

You could also choose to use a test on the output of `uname`, obviously,

```bsh
if [ "$(uname)" = Darwin ]; then
    # Assumes GNU tar is gtar on macOS and that it's available
    tar=gtar
else
    # Assumes GNU tar is tar on this system, and that it's available
    tar=tar
fi

"$tar" --sort=name --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 --mtime='UTC 2020-01-01' -cvf api.tar api
```

Comment: Re. your suggestion for setting on the global `$PATH`: I had considered this, but I'm keen to avoid modifying OS commands.  For example, another script (not written by me) might do something like `if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]];` and then continue to use `tar` expecting it to behave like BSD tar.

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield I left you with a number of suggestions. Pick one that fits your needs.  You can also modify `PATH` in a subshell: `( PATH=...; tar ... )`.  That way you use a locally modified `PATH`.  Alternatively, make `tar` a shell function that does this for you, and declare `PATH` as `local` in there (make sure to call the real `tar` using `command tar` or `command gtar` in this function as to not make a recursive call).  I mean, there are so many ways you can solve this.

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda :+1: